# finding the biggest sequence of repeating numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, sequence

The problem to solve is to find the biggest sequence of repeating numbers in a list. For example if the list was `[2,3,4,4,4,5,4,7,6]` and I was looking for the largest sequence of 4's, I would return 3.

So far, I've only come up with a loop that counts the number of the specified number in a row but you have to account for the other numbers and also have a way to compare say, 3 "4's" in a row versus 2 "4's". any help would be appreciated

```
def find(list):
    x = [2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8]  
    print(find(x))
```

the code above is just the basic layout. I don't need the answer to the whole function but just the main logic and explanations

Comment: The whole point about homework is to do it on your own. Stencil/paper will do the trick at first. Plus, there is no code to help you about; you did not try anything nor give any clue whatsoever conerning your strategy for solving this. PLEASE SHOW SOME EFFORT.

Comment: there are many ways to do this, first thing that comes into my head is brute force, other way `2-pointer` approach

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement this in Python, you should use `groupby`. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), by default, groups objects into tuples of `(object_name, list_of_objects)`, so:

```py
a = [1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
groupby(a) ~ [(1, [1]), (0, [0]), (1, [1, 1]), (2, [2, 2, 2]), (3, [3])]
# I use "~" here because it's not actually a list, it's a generator, but meh
```

You can easily use a list comprehension to grab what you need.

```py
from itertools import groupby
repeat_lengths = [sum(1 for _ in group) for _, group in groupby(x)]
# the `sum(1 for _ in group)` is a workaround for the fact that `group` is not a list and has no length
```

Then just find the max of that list.

Comment: Notably if this is homework, you'll likely receive zero points for this solution since it offloads all the algorithmic work to a stdlib function.

Comment: Needless to say, you won't learn the basics behind the said libs !

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `len()` with a generator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of two variables, the current count `(count)` of the consecutive values and the maximum count `(max_count)` so far. When you observe a different value, you reset `count` and update `max_count` and continue the loop.

```
def get_longest_seq(l, val):
  count = 0
  max_count = 0
  for e in l:
    if e == val:
      count += 1
    elif count > 0:
      max_count = max(max_count, count)
      count = 0
  max_count = max(max_count, count) # case when the sequence is at the end
  return max_count

l = [2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,4,7,6]
print(get_longest_seq(l, 4))
```